# CSS width and height property from background-image property

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if I the title's correct, so feel free to edit it to something more descriptive.

**How to, if there's a way to, read the width/height of an background-image image and pass it to width/height property of that element in CSS (without the use of JavaScript)?**

So, since I think the question is still confusing, I'll best provide an example:

```
element {
    background: url(image.png);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

I know the above example doesn't work, but I was wondering if there is something similar to it that might.

Thanks!

P.S: I can do it in JS, so posting a JS solution won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with only CSS.

I'm not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: Ah well, thanks anyway. I'll just type them in manually, then. xoxo

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible - workaraound is to put there img , set overflow to hidden, and put second div in with position relative ( it some setup to fit it all, but it works )